# ASP & Javascript: Relative Path Issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, relative-path, jplayer

I'm at wits end with this. I'm doing a contract with a client that uses ASP and am pretty unfamiliar with it. I'm using something called jPlayer for the video functionality. jPlayer will use HTML5 video if it can, and if not it falls back to a Flash plugin. When you setup the player object, you point it to the directory where the Flash player resides.

My problem, after many hours of running around in circles, is that I can't seem to get this path to work when the page is saved as ".aspx" and has the ASPnet features. When I save it as ".html" it works flawlessly. Has anyone ever ran into this issue before? Here's the code that initiates jPlayer:

```
$(this).siblings('.jPlayer').jPlayer({
    swfPath: "scripts/jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/",
    solution: 'flash, html',
    supplied: 'm4v',
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#j_controls_"+cur_ctrl,
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4v: file 
        });                 
        $(this).jPlayer("play");
    },
    wmode: "opaque"
})
```

Comment: Why not use an absolute path?

Comment: I've tried this as well and it didn't seem to work. Here's the absolute path:http://testwww.chicagobooth.edu/faculty/scripts/jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/Jplayer.swf

Answer (score 0):

Is all your markup pure html? Or are you using any asp-controls? If you use controls like  then you should be wary that the id specified by such markup is altered serverside before rendering. Also mind that your page might include a master-page which includes various other markup and js. It's hard to tell you what is wrong with this little information.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an aspx file as an instruction to the server, rather than to the client. There is no direct 1:1 mapping to what will eventually be sent to the client. Something that will be accessed at `/some/path/with/subdirectories/test.aspx` might be the *exact same document* as something accessed at `/root/test.aspx`, for instance.

When the client receives an instruction to download `script/jPlayer.js`, the HTTP request constructed will be entirely different depending on at which of the two addresses the aspx is loaded.

The most reliable way forward is to access your file from the application root, i.e. with a leading `/` in the path.

If you can't figure out why your script isn't being loaded by looking at the path alone, use your browser inspection tools to see at what path it is really trying to load your resources, and where you're getting a 404.

It may well be that your jPlayer file loads perfectly fine, but that the jPlayer script in turn uses relative paths to load another resource, and that this is where you get a 404.